# Get user ID of the person using the send dialog in Facebook JS SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook

I want to create the option for our users to share an item on our site using the facebook send dialog. The user needs to select the friends he or she wants to share the content with. After that I want to know the user ID's of the person who send it and the persons send to so I can create a private part on the site where the users can discuss the product.

I was thinking about solving that using a unique number as parameter in the item's redirect url and add the facebook user ID's to that in the database. That way I can create the relation between the user who send the message (and his friends) and the particular item they want to discuss privately.

```
FB.ui({
       method: 'send',
       name: 'People Argue Just to Win',
       link: 'http://www.nytimes.com/2011/06/15/arts/people-argue-just-to-win-scholars-assert.html',
       display: 'popup',
       },
       function(response) {
           console.log(response);
       });
```

The response object only holds a success bool and I can't find a way to get more information about the result. Any ideas on how to solve this otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is not possible as it would be a breach of user privacy.

If the user is authenticated with your app, you can access their Facebook ID, and if you use the requests dialog (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) instead of the send button, you'll get a response which will give you the user IDs of the people who have been sent a request.